# PyTorch Tensor broadcasting

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, broadcast

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following broadcast:

I have two tensors, of sizes (n1,N) and (n2,N)

What I want to do is to multiply each row of the first tensor, with each row of the second tensor, and then sum each of there multiplied row result, so that my final tensor should be of the form (n1,n2).

I tried this:

```
x1*torch.reshape(x2,(x2.size(dim=0),x2.size(dim=1),1))
```

But obviously this doesn't work.. Can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe seems to be effectively the same as performing a matrix multiplication between the first tensor and the transpose of the second tensor. This can be done as:

```
torch.matmul(x1, x2.T)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the `Tensordot` command from [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensordot.html) and [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)

Since you want to compute dot product along N, which is dimension 1 of `x1`, and dimension 1 of `x2` tensor, you need to perform a contraction along the first axes of both Tensors by supplying a `([1], [1])` to `dims` arg in Tensordot. This means Torch will sum products of `x1` and `x2` elements over the specified x1-axes `1` and specified x2-axes `1` respectively. The args to supply to `dims` is quite confusing, here's a useful thread to help understand how to use `Tensordot`[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63074/is-there-a-3-dimensional-matrix-by-matrix-product)

```
x1 = torch.arange(6.).reshape(2,3) 
>>> tensor([[0., 1., 2.],
            [3., 4., 5.]])
# x1 is Tensor of shape (2,3)

x2 = torch.arange(9.).reshape(3,3)
>>> tensor([[0., 1., 2.],
            [3., 4., 5.],
            [6., 7., 8.]])
# x2 is Tensor of shape (3,3)

x = torch.tensordot(x1, x2, dims=([1],[1]))
>>> tensor([[ 5., 14., 23.],
            [14., 50., 86.]])
# x is Tensor of shape (2,3)
```